# VueJS Setup in Laravel

Tags: laravel, gulp, vue.js

I installed VueJS2 for usage in laravel. 
Starting with a simple test setup, this is `app.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MEDIFAKTOR - @yield('title') </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        @include('layouts.navigation')
        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
            <!-- Page wrapper -->
            @include('layouts.topnavbar')
            <!-- Main view  -->
            @yield('content')
            <!-- Footer -->
            @include('layouts.footer')
        </div>
        <!-- End page wrapper-->
    </div>
    <!-- End wrapper-->
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
      var data = {
          message: 'Greetings your majesty'
      };
      new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: data
      })
  </script>
  @section('scripts')
@show
</body>
</html>
```

and this the content I want to display

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Main page')
@section('content')
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="text-center m-t-lg">
                            <h1>MEDIFAKTOR server</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="app">
                            <h1>{{message}}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
@endsection
```

When I refresh, I get the error:

> ErrorException in 80e040fb5fff0b0cf766194784388a0cd255e6c9.php line
>   10: Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Development/Source/MFServer/resources/views/home/index.blade.php)

This sounds to me, like VueJS is not recognized. I installed according to VueJS website and laracasts.com

Did I place it a the wrong spots?

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: {{message}} is not defined for index blade... please post controller code which load the index blade..... use @{{message}} instead {{message}} if vueJS variable..... {{varibale}} search for php variable but @{{variable}} search for JS variavle i mean VueJS

Answer (score 3):

Try to use **@{{message}}** instead of {{message}} in your index blade. because your message is not php variable its JS framework variable. put **@** sign before the variable.

Comment: Thanks, now the content is not being replaced by I see on the website "{{message}}" displayed. So the variable is not filled with the content. I have the feeling that VUEJS is still not recognized? The dev console show this error (index):96 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
But I inserted the CDN link in the app.blade.php

Comment: In you main JS file for the app you need to have "import Vue from 'vue'" and then you JS can recognize what is "Vue". Yes you have the CDN but in VueJS you need to import individual modules and make available throughout whole execution. this is the good resource https://learninglaravel.net/topics/vuejs , visit the link and have research first.

Answer (score 1):

If you solved the problem with sign **@**, but still get an error "Vue is not defined", as you said in the comment, you have a typo in your code - you should use attribute **src**, not **scr**. So the correct including of the vue.min.js should looks like that:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js"></script>
```

---

Also you can get a problem when your JS code is starting to execute before vue.min.js is loaded, try to use onload event for vue JS file:

```
<script onload="vueIsReady()" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function vueIsReady(){
      var data = {
          message: 'Greetings your majesty'
      };
      new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: data
      })
}
</script>
```

Or you can use importScript function from this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement

```
// definition of the function importScript ...

// call function importScript with two parameters - script URL and onload handler function
importScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js', function(){
    function vueIsReady(){
      var data = {
          message: 'Greetings your majesty'
      };
      new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: data
      })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems getting to render vuejs' curly braces {{}}.
@{{}} should do the trick or to make things simpler
you may consider blade's
  @verbatim
   html code {{vuejs_vars}}
  @endverbatim

verbatim tags in blade make sure that any between them doesnt get parsed by the blade engine & are printed as is.

Answer (score 0):

Vue is declared in assets/bootstrap.js. So, check there. If it's in place, perhaps debug at the created hook on the Vue instance:

```
created: function () {
console.log('instance created')
}
```

Try to debug from there.